# .NET Enumeration inheritance alternative

Tags: .net, inheritance, pinvoke, enumeration

I'd like to create an enumeration for [`ACCESS_MASK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374892.aspx) i have to use with *P/Invoke*, but i do not know what would be the best way for such an inplementation.

**1. If it were possible:**

```
[Flags]
enum ACCESS_MASK : uint
{
    STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000,
    SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000,
    // Everything reused in the specific rights ...
}

[Flags]
enum PROCESS_ACCESS_MASK : ACCESS_MASK
{
    // ...
    PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | SYNCHRONIZE | 0xFFFF,
}
```

**2. Everything  in one:** *(No automatic string representation possible)*

```
[Flags]
enum ACCESS_MASK : uint
{
    STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000,
    SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000,
    // ...
    PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | SYNCHRONIZE | 0xFFFF,
}
```

**3. Split and rewrite:** *(Muuuuch duplicate code)*

```
[Flags]
enum PROCESS_ACCESS_MASK : uint
{
    STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000,
    SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000,
    // ...
    PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | SYNCHRONIZE | 0xFFFF,
}
```

**4. Split and take from basic:** *(Specific enum doesn't know anything about the basic values itself)*

```
[Flags]
enum ACCESS_MASK : uint
{
    STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000,
    SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000,
    // Everything reused in the specific rights ...
}

[Flags]
enum PROCESS_ACCESS_MASK : uint
{
    // ...
    PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = ACCESS_MASK.STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | ACCESS_MASK.SYNCHRONIZE | 0xFFFF,
}
```

**Which option do you prefer, or are there any better ways for an `ACCESS_MASK` implementation?**

*Btw: whats a 0x100001 file access?*

*Edit: I know there is no enumeration inheritance and `ACCESS_MASK : uint` is nothing like that, but the imaginary `PROCESS_ACCESS_MASK : ACCESS_MASK` would be.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are hiding the P/Invoke details from the rest of the application, and that the `ACCESS_MASK` values are only used very locally, I'd just put all options into one single enum - your option 2.

Additionally, I'd mark the enum with [`FlagsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) to indicate that it is treated as a bit field.

Comment: Uh, forgot that `FlagsAttribute`, of course. I'm currently using that second option, but sadly my application needs something like: _"give me the access mask and i'll tell you what rights components you're using."_

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the code in context; but as long as there are no bits with conflicting definitions I'd just work on the union of all definitions. Of course this changes if you also need to validate (*"give me the access mask and I'll tell you the components - and it it is valid for your type of object"*).

Comment: Gladly no validation. I get different kind of handles _(i know the type)_ and their `ACCESS_MASK` and then have to say how they are opened. Problem is that, for example, `PROCESS_TERMINATE` has the same value as `FILE_READ_DATA` _(and there are much more types: keys,threads,events,tokens,...)_

Comment: One way to resolve this would be to create a `Scope` flags enum, specifying the type (process, thread, event, token,…), and to mark each enum element with a custom `MaskScopeAttribute`. When resolving components you could then filter by the appropriate scope.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do:

```
public enum ACCESS_MASK : uint
{
    STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000,
    SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000,
    // Everything reused in the specific rights ...
}

public static class Masks
{
    // ...
    public const ACCESS_MASK PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = ACCESS_MASK.STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | ACCESS_MASK.SYNCHRONIZE | (ACCESS_MASK) 0xFFFF;
}
```

This way you keep the enum in the preferred form. This was inspired on on how Winforms defines the `Color` class with specific `Colors` in a separate static class.